# Submit Form Using React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using react-redux hooks.I want to dispatch an action after some validations when the form is submitted. But I cannot call `usedispatch()` hook outside function component. Is there any way I can dispatch an action using `usedispatch()` ?

My code looks as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { register } from '../../actions/auth';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

let state = {
    username: '',
    password1: '',
    password2: '',

}
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    if (state.password1 === state.password2) {
        dispatch(register(state))
    }
    else {
        console.log('Psw did not matched.')
    }
}
const onChange = (e) => {
    let field_name = e.target.name;
    state[field_name] = e.target.value;
}
const Register = () => {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
            <div className="card card-body mt-5">
                <h2 className="text-center">Register</h2>
                <form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="username"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label> Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="password1"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="password2"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Register;
```

I get an error that React Hooks cannot be used outside function component and it is obvious. I am looking for a way to dispatch `register` action after doing some validation when form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing a React component, it would make sense if you define your state within and other functions within the component. This way you would be able to use hook, useDispatch as well. Also you can make your input fields controlled instead of letting them be uncontrolled

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { register } from '../../actions/auth';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";


const Register = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
            username: '',
            password1: '',
            password2: '',
    });
    const onChange = (e) => {
        let field_name = e.target.name;
        let field_value = e.target.value;
        setState(prev => ({...prev, [field_name]: field_value});
    }
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (state.password1 === state.password2) {
            dispatch(register(state))
        }
        else {
            console.log('Psw did not matched.')
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
            <div className="card card-body mt-5">
                <h2 className="text-center">Register</h2>
                <form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="username"
                            value={state.username}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label> Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="password1"
                            value={state.password1}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="password2"
                            value={state.password2}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Register;
```

Comment: This makes no difference. Defining state and other function inside function component also gives same error.

Comment: If you notice, I moved your useDispatch from within onSubmit function to the component

Comment: It still give 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.' message.

Comment: are you using v16.8 or above of react, react dom. Also are you using the latest version of redux

Comment: I am using react and react dom of v17.0.1, redux v4.0.5 and react-redux v7.2.3